# Show selected form values - before submit?

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

I'm looking to use `onClick="return confirm('are you sure ?')"` to get users to confirm what they are submitting.

Basic form is:

```
<form>
<Select name='val[]' class='select'><option></option><option value='a'>a</option><option value='b'>b</option><option value='c'>c</option><option value='d'>d</option></select>
<Select name='opt'><option>AAA</option><option>BBB</option><option>CCC</option></select>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit' onClick="return confirm('are you sure ?')">
</form>
```

When they click submit how do I update the return confirm to show the values they have selected from the dropdown lists?

**edit:**

I should have mentioned this page is using the Jquery Chosen script from http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

The first option is a multiselect and is using chosen to make it look nicer.

The suggestion from **dishwasherWithProgrammingSkill** works but doesn't show the multivalues selected.

Anyway to do that ?

**Update:**
Using :         `var opt3=$('#opt1').val();`

Returns me a comma separated list. How do I remove the commas ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any php or any jquery here, please re-tag. (try javascript)

Comment: It will be easiest if you get your code out of the tag and into a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
<form>
    <select name='val' class='select' id='opt1'>
        <option></option>
        <option value='a'>a</option>
        <option value='b'>b</option>
    </select>
    <select name='opt' id='opt2'>
        <option value='AAA'>AAA</option>
        <option value='BBB'>BBB</option>
    </select>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit' onClick="return function1();">
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    function function1(){
        var opt1=document.getElementById("opt1").value;
        var opt2=document.getElementById("opt2").value;
        var response=confirm("Are you sure? option1="+opt1+" option2="+opt2);
        return response;
     }
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

Since you already got the values by using `var opt3=$('#opt1').val();` the rest is easy, use the split() function in javascript. It is similar to the explode() function in php.
here is the sample.

```
var opt3=$('#opt1').val();
var valArray=opt3.split(",");  //The parameter determines where you want to split.
for (var i = 0; i < valArray.length; i++) {
    alert(valArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: Ahh. slight problem. my first select can have multiple values, this only shows the first. I'm using http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ to support the multiple values.. any idea how to make this work ?

Comment: Select statement can only pass one value at a time. The plug in that you are using provides a drop down menu in a text box and fills it up after you select an option. You will need to pass the value from that text box instead of the select statement.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write a function for it. Using jquery you can use $(form).submit(function(){}); to pull your values in on submit, show the confirm dialog and set the content.

Let me know how you do!

http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to separate your javascript from your form, and add an event listener.  But, if you still want to use `onclick` you could add an `id` to each of your form elements, and get the value using `getElementById()` -

```
<form>
    <select name='val[]' id='val' class='select'><option></option><option value='a'>a</option><option value='b'>b</option><option value='c'>c</option><option value='d'>d</option></select>
    <select name='opt' id='opt'><option>AAA</option><option>BBB</option><option>CCC</option></select>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit' onClick="return confirm('are you sure? val='+getElementById('val').value +' opt='+getElementById('opt').value)" />
</form>
```

see this jsFiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/rpcBS/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to listen for onSubmit() and not onClick()

```
<form onSubmit="return confirm('are you sure?);">
    <Select name='val[]' class='select'><option></option><option value='a'>a</option><option value='b'>b</option><option value='c'>c</option><option value='d'>d</option></select>
    <Select name='opt'><option>AAA</option><option>BBB</option><option>CCC</option></select>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

onClick will not stop the form from submitting.

Comment: onclick works on input type="submit". 

`<input type="submit" onclick="alert ('see it works')">`

Comment: Yes the alert will work but it will not stop the form from submitting.

Comment: check the code that I just posted below :D. You need to have a boolean return type to make it work.